# Adding component to the API package in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: journeybuilder, authentication, component, installedpackage

I'm installing this api package for a Journey API Entry Point through **Installed Packages**. The Add Component keeps saying "Unable to complete update this time". I'm trying to create a Journey Builder Entry Source for the Component Type.

I gave the the component the following a name, description and the endpoint URL. I think the endpoint URL is causing the issue. I picked the tenant endpoint from account settings under but that doesn't seem to be right since it only provides a SOAP Service Endpoint. Where do I get the proper endpoint so I can save this component?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Though Journey API Entry Point is what I am looking for, the Component is still Server to Server. So the selection is API Integration and not Journey Builder Entry Source.